# Exponentials to the negative power

Tags: exponentiation

Could someone please help me in showing how
$$xe^{-nx}\le\frac1n$$
I don't totally see why the LHS is bounded by the RHS.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  let $f(x)=xe^{-nx}$.  For which $x$ is that a maximum?

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to
$$
e^{nx}\ge nx
$$
or
$$
e^t\ge t
$$
Consider $f(t)=e^t-t$, compute its minimum and conclude.